# How can I find array value occurrences and missing ones in a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Considering an array of numeric strings, e.g. arr = ['202', '303', '1', ...] and the following table:

```
MyTable
code VARCHAR(255)
```

Is possible to find in a single query:

1. All values in arr which doesn't exists in MyTable.code?
2. All values of MyTable.code which doesn't exists in arr?

There's some way to achieve that?

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unnest the array and use `join`s or something similar

For the first condition:

```
select el
from unnest(ar) el 
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.code = el);
```

Similar logic can be used for the second, but you might want `select distinct`:

```
select t.code
from t 
where not exists (select 1 from unnest(ar) el  where t.code = el);
```

If you want both in a single query, you can use `union all` or `full join`:

```
select el, t.code
from unnest(ar) el full join
     t 
     on t.code = el
where t.code is null or el is null;
```

Comment: Amazing answer!